# protractor testing on multi select giving 'Element not visible' error

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, protractor

I have the following html code with a multiselect element. On running tests with protractor to select the options, I get the error as 'Element not visible'.

```
    <div id="one" class="class1">
    <select id="select1" style="width: 70%;" class="multiselect" multiple="multiple" ng-model="formData.abcqw">
    <option value="abc">ABC</option>
    <option value="xyz">XYZ</option>
    <option value="pqr">PQR</option>
    </select>
    </div>


     protractor code :  
     browser.actions().
     mouseMove(element(by.className("multiselect"))).click().perform();
     element(by.model("formData.abcqw")).sendKeys("abc");
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please post the code you have tried

Comment: have edited the code above

Comment: Why do you click in the `multiselect` first? Does it open a dropdown? Also which element is not visible? One simple thing to try anyway is using this as elementFinder in both of your Protractor lines `$('#select1.multiselect')` -> (looks for id=select1 and class=multiselect).

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty much evident from the `HTML` which you have shared that the `<select>` tag is an `AngularJS` element, so we have to induce `wait` i.e. `WebDriverWait` as follows for the element to be selectable:

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
// Waits for the element with id 'select1' to be selected.
browser.wait(EC.elementToBeSelected($('#select1')), 5000);
```

Comment: ok, thanks. But should i put a wait before the mouse click or after it.

Comment: We have to put the wait before the mouse click only.

Comment: it waits but it does not select the element , tried it with a longer wait too.

Comment: Well, No. Its a Select tag, try to use `Select` class

Comment: it actually waits before the click but on execution of the click it breaks out, has it not located the element? During the wait it does not perform the mouse click?

Answer (score 0):

I also think that it is a wait issue.
Whenever you see this "element not visible error" you can add

```
browser.sleep(5000);
```

before the click statement  and try again

if that doesn't work try below.
This when we intentionally want to click an hidden element. So this should work

```
  var elm = element(by.className("multiselect "));
    browser.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", elm.getWebElement());
    browser.sleep(2000);
    element(by.model("formData.abcqw")).sendKeys("abc");
```

Comment: Please let me know whether it works or else we can debug more

Comment: thanks. tried sleep , this too does not work, browser waits for the specified time before click however when the click happens it breaks with the error.

Comment: Are you sure this is a unique locator and there no duplicate elements ?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code, I replicated the same in my local and verified the below code it works fine:

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
var multiSelectElement = element(by.model('formData.abcqw');
browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(multiSelectElement))).then(function() {
    browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(multiSelectElement.element(by.cssContainingText('option', 'ABC'))))).then(function() {
        multiSelectElement.element(by.cssContainingText('option', 'ABC')).click();
    }); 
});
```